# What does Vallabhacharya's Shuddhadvaita Vedanta say about Nirguna Brahman?

Tags: vedanta, brahman

In Advaita Vedanta, Nirguna Brahman is the supreme. What does Vallabhacharya of the Pushtimarga sect say about Nirguna Brahman?

Comment: [Introduction to Suddhadvaita](http://www.vallabhkankroli.org/pdfs/Introduction%20to%20Shuddadvaita.pdf) (based on Anubhashya) may be of your interest.

Comment: Acc. to Vallabhacharya, It is "Nirguna Brahman" because he is free from the qualities of prakrti. And all the souls are "parts of Brahman"

Comment: @KrishnShweta What is the definition of Nirguna Brahman according to Vallabhacharya?

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury 1) Nirguna doesn't mean attributeless like Advaita, but it means it has divine qualities and those are Satt, Chit and Anand. 2) It is not nirakar, it has limbs but they are blissful.